# Как в hql выборке учесть отсутствие валидных кортежей?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Есть метод, который ходит в базу и достает пользователя по паре `login` и `password`. Проблема в том, что если такого пользователя не оказывается то программа падает с `javax.persistence.NoResultException` :

```
public User getUser(final String login, final String password) {

    User result;

    final String hql = String.format("%s%s", "select u from User u ",
            "where u.login = :login and u.password = :password");

    try (final Session session = factory.get().openSession()) {

        result = session.createQuery(hql, User.class)
                .setParameter("login", login)
                .setParameter("password", password)
                .getSingleResult();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Вот результат неудачной выборки:

```
javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1465)
    ru.pravvich.dao.DAOImpl.getUser(DAOImpl.java:48)
    ru.pravvich.servlet.AuthFilter.userIsRegisteredDB(AuthFilter.java:58)
    ru.pravvich.servlet.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:36)
    ru.pravvich.servlet.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:26)
```

Можно ли это исправить так, чтобы не надо было отдельный запрос делать?

Таблица `users`, по которой идет выборка:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
     id SERIAL NOT NULL ,
     login TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL ,
     password TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL ,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здравствуйте.
Предлагаю 2 пути решения.

## try-catch для javax.persistence.NoResultException

```
try (final Session session = factory.get().openSession()) {

    result = session.createQuery(hql, User.class)
            .setParameter("login", login)
            .setParameter("password", password)
            .getSingleResult();
}
catch(NoResultException e) {
   //обработать эту ситуацию явно
   //например, result = null;
}
```

## Использовать query.list()

```
{
    List listResult = session.createQuery(hql, User.class)
                .setParameter("login", login)
                .setParameter("password", password)
                .list();
    if(!listResult.isEmpty()) { // или if(listResult.size() != 0)
            result = (User)listResult.get(0);
    } else {
        result = null;
    }
}
```